# conflicts with angular and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to navigate from one url to other which is present in `navigation dropdown bar`. It shows jquery error. But it navigates properly when I place in other places at html page.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/details/
```

because of this line I am getting conflicts how to resolve it

```
$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;
        if(hash.length > 1){
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 'slow');  
        }
});
```

and in index file this is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/lib/parallax.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/master/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

In controller.js this is the code

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home-folder/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  }).
  when('/details', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/details-folder/detail.html',
    controller: 'DetailCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

From html I wanted to call the detail page But I am getting the above error... None of them are working from below example

```
<a href="#/details/">test1</a>
<a href="#/details">test2</a>
<a href="/details/">test3</a>
<a href="/details">test4</a>
```

Comment: why not use `ng-click`

Comment: what to write in ng-click can you tell me the full code

Comment: I tried like this  `<li><a href="" ng-click="$location.path( '/details' );">Others</a></li>` but unable to succeed

Comment: also use `ng-href="/details"`

Comment: on `ng-click=animate()`  and in `animate` function write your animation code

Comment: If I comment nav bar click event code it works fine. I tried in all the ways but unable to suceed

Comment: Provide  demo that replicates your problem. The jQuery part doesn't really make sense mixed with using router and you probab;y want to use `$anchorScroll`

Comment: I got the solution for it.... because of `jquery nav click` event I am getting conflicts. I converted it to angular code and now it works fine